# Can type classes be applied to sealed traits?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to have a type class that is applied to a sealed trait?

The following sealed Trait

```
sealed trait MyType
object Type1 extends MyType
object Type2 extends MyType
case class Type3(i:Int) extends MyType
```

And I want to enrich the trait with a 'show' function that can be represented using the following type class

`trait Show[A] {
  def show(a: A): String
}`

And I would like to us it in a function that accepts a trait as an input

```
def show[A :< MyType](a: A)(implicit sh: Show[A]) = sh.show(a) // Will not compile
```

Usually I could do something like

```
 implicit val type3CanShow: Show[Type3] =
new Show[Type3] {
  def show(t: Type3): String = s"show ${t.i}"
}
```

To get this to work I have 2 problems:
1) How do I define the type class on a object instead of a class (i.e Type1 and Type 2)
2) How do I get it to accept work on a trait, and make sure that the type class is provided for 3 products of the sealed trait

To solve 2 I could do something like  (doen't compile - assumes all 3 were case classes)

```
def show[A :< MyType](a: A)(implicit sh: Show[A]) =
  a match { 
     case t: Type1 =>  sh.show(t)
     case t: Type2 =>  sh.show(t)
     case t: Type3 =>  sh.show(t)
  }
```

UPDATE:
@thesamet solved 1. However, I would still like a better way to do 2. 
Running code like this, without having to add the pattern matching from above
 
`def doSomething(t: MyType) = {
   show(t)
}`

Answer (score 1):

The code you pasted

```
def show[A :< MyType](a: A)(implicit sh: Show[A]) = sh.show(a) // Will not compile
```

does not compile since it should be `<:` and not `:<` to specify `MyType` as the upperbound for A. The following does compile:

```
def show[A <: MyType](a: A)(implicit sh: Show[A]) = sh.show(a)
```

To define an implicit value for `Type1` you have to specify the type of the singleton object:

```
implicit val ShowType1 = new Show[Type1.type] {
  def show(a: Type1.type) = "Type1"
}
```

Similarly for `Type2`:

```
implicit val ShowType2 = new Show[Type2.type] {
  def show(a: Type2.type) = "Type2"
}
```

Try it!

```
println(show(Type1))
```

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo. Type1.type is what I was looking for. Any advice on a better solution to 1 than what I have? (i.e automatically getting a type class from the base trait)

Comment: @EugeneMi can you clarify what you mean by automatically getting a type class from a base trait?

Comment: @EugeneMi - did this answer address your question?

Comment: - Yes, but still trying to find a nicer way to do 2 (see updated question)

Comment: To clarify (2), do you want to get an error at compile time when there exists any trait, class or an object that extends MyType that is not associated with a type class?

Comment: Also, why isn't "def show" as defined in this answer is not what you are looking for?